# php 2d array ... store mysql results in 2d array

Tags: php

I have a sql statement that returns a number of records each having 10 attributes. How can i get the data and put it into a 2D array. Currently Im doing this :

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    echo $row1[0][1]; //There is an error here
}
```

Is $row1 a 2D array? (It should be because Im getting n*m results). If $row1 is a 2d array then shouldn't i be able to access $row[0][1]?

Comment: what happens if you print_r the $row1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

If [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) is recovering 1 row of data, what do you expect the second dimension to be?

First off you need to verify what sort of array you are getting, then you can understand why your keys aren't valid.  Try using `print_r` or `var_dump` to examine $row1.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch array returns a 1-D array, combined indexed + keyed values of one single row of data from your query results. e.g. doing

SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM sometable

and doing a mysql_fetch_array on the result will give you an array that looks like:

```
$row1 = array(
    0 => 'value of field1',
    1 => 'value of field2',
    2 => 'value of field3',
    'field1' => 'value of field1'
    'field2' => 'value of field2',
    'field3' => 'value of field3'
)
```

If you want to address the entire result set as a single array, you'll have to fetch each row and add it to that array first:

```
$data = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row1;
}
```

Which would let you do `$data[0][1]` (2nd field [1] of 1st record [0])

Answer (score 0):

`$row1` holds only one record at a time so it is a regular one-dimension array.

If your query returns

```
a    b    c
d    e    f
```

In the first iteration of the while loop, `row1` holds `a b  c` and in the second iteration, it holds `d   e   f`, both single-dimension arrays.

Comment: how can i change it to a 2d array?

Comment: See Marc B's answer for how to make it into a 2-D array

Answer (score 0):

$row1 is a 1-dimensional array (a single record), in your case, holding 10 values.

As the code loops through the while statement, $row1 represents each record.

refer to the documentation here: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php